# How to solve a quadratic polynomial in 4 variable?

Tags: functions, algorithms, quadratics

I'm trying to find an (smallest) integer solution of the equation
$$F(x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1) = (a\cdot x_0 +b\cdot x_1) \cdot (a\cdot y_0  + b\cdot y_1) - c,$$

where $a,b,c$ are known integers and ($x_0, x_1, y_0, y_1)$ are variables.

I already know that this equation has the smallest integer solution $(X_0,X_1, Y_0,Y_1)$
(with respect to Euclidean norm).

**Question:** Is there an algorithm to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $c\neq 0$, otherwise the problem is rather trivial. Clearly, if there is a solution, $ax_0+bx_1$ is a divisor $d$ of $c$, and in this case the other factor is $c/d$.

Hence you have to solve the two equations $ax_0+bx_1=d$ and $ay_0+by_1=c/d$ for each divisor $d$.

But the equation $au+bv=m$ is easily solved (where $a,b,m$ are given integers, and $m$ is not zero)

It has a solution if and only if $\delta=gcd(a,b)$ divides $m$.

If so, dividing by this gcd , it remains to solve $a'u+b'v=m'$ where $a'=a/\delta, b'=b\delta, m'=m/\delta$. Note that $a',b'$ are coprime.

Now use Euclid algorithm to find $\alpha,\beta$ such that $a'\alpha+b'\beta=1$, and set $u_0=m\alpha, v_0=m\beta$. Then $a'u+b'v=m=a'u_0+b'v_0$. Using the fact that $a',b'$ are  coprime, we see that $u=u_0+kb',v=v_0-ka', k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's a good direction. But unfortunately, we don't know the factors of c. (As you said, we consider that c is nonzero). If then, what should we do?

Comment: Well, if you now $c$, you know its divisors, no? Could you be more precise on what you want ? If this is a computer algebra problem , that is, if you consider that you don't know how to factor $c$ efficiently because it is too big, then your problem is kinda hopeless i think.  I'm not a specialist in computer algebra, so I might be wrong, but  finding solutions of you equations seems equivalent to  finding divisors of $c$. Indeed, if you have a divisor, you have solutions, but if you have solutions, then you have divisors of $c$.